# Looping through a multivalued field and embedded schema field in .NET Assembly TBB

Tags: tridion

I am working on creating .NET TBB for Tridion 2011 SP1. I have two fields in the component where one is single valued and other is embedded schema field.

To retrieve the single valued field, i have used

```
string singlefield= package.GetValue("Component.Fields.singlefield");
```

but to refer multivalued field i have used.

```
string multi= package.GetValue("Component.Fields.multi.values");
```

But its not fetching the values.

Please help a way of doing it.

Comment: Is your embedded field multivalue field?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wouldn't use package.GetValue for any value in a component. Instead, use something like this:

```cs
// Get the component
Component c = (Component)engine.GetObject(package.GetByName(Package.ComponentName));
// Get the fields
ItemFields fields = new ItemFields(c.Content, c.Schema);
// get our Embedded schema field
EmbeddedSchemaField emb = (EmbeddedSchemaField)fields["emb"];
// Loop
foreach (ItemFields embeddedfields in emb.Values)
{
    foreach (ItemField field in embeddedfields)
    {
        var tField = field as TextField;
        if (tField != null)
        {
            string something = tField.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this:

```
package.GetValue("Component.Fields.emb.multi[0]");
```

Where `emb` is the name of the field in component schema and `multi` is the multiple value field from your embeddable schema. `[0]` is field index, but it's optional

Comment: @muzimil If you are sure that there will be no commas in the field you might get field value `Component.Fields.emb.multi` and then split it by comma, but I'm afraid the only other way will be to read content of a component and then parse XML